# Embedding $\mathbb{Z}$ into a $\mathbb{Q}$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

$\mathbb{Z}$ is not a $\mathbb{Q}$-module since if $\frac{1}{2}\cdot1=x\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $2x=1$, which is absurd. However, according to Dummit and Foote (3rd Ed, page 359), there exists an embedding of the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}$ into the $\mathbb{Q}$-module $\mathbb{Q}$.

What is the embedding? I don't believe such a map exists since $\mathbb{Z}\cong i(\mathbb{Z})$ as groups. On the other hand, I cannot prove that the isomorphism forces both groups to not be $\mathbb{Q}$modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just the inclusion map: if $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $i(n)=n$ (thinking of an integer as also being a rational number in the usual way).  Maybe your confusion comes from the fact that this is an embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, not an embedding of $\mathbb{Q}$-modules.  Of course you can't have an embedding of $\mathbb{Q}$-modules from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a $\mathbb{Q}$-module to begin with.

(There are also many other embeddings: for any nonzero $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, $i(n)=nq$ is also an embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.)

Answer (score 2):

You already know how $\Bbb Z\hookrightarrow\Bbb Q$. The embedding is just an embedding of $\Bbb Z$-modules, obviously not an embedding of $\Bbb Q$-modules. In fact D&F state just above that $\Bbb Z$ cannot be made a $\Bbb Q$-module, and just below generalizes the question by asking when an $R$-module can be embedded as an $R$-submodule of an $S$-module, where $R$ is a subring of $S$.